# Continuous measurement of urea concentration in water

Tags: ph, spectroscopy, concentration, conductivity

My colleague and I are working with fertilizers, and we are trying to continuously measure the concentration of urea in water (In situ concentration as function of time). There are two condition that we're considering, first is using distilled water, and second is with the present of some salt (i.e., KCl (0.1 mM-10mM)). Our expected concentration is within 0.1-100 mM

---

Is it possible to use pH meter, conductometer, or something similar? How would that even work?

---

Have there been anyone who've done this before?

Comment: A method can be easy, cheap or usable. Choose 2 of 3. // BTW, what concentration?

Comment: Also, what is the water quality(solute composition) and are there additional additivies? The more relevant details you provide, the more suitable answers you may get, as the optimal method choice may depend on it, if there is ever any simple/cheap enough applicable.

Comment: See [Is there any method to determine urea (in water) and phosphate (KH2PO4 in water) fertilizers by UV-VIS spectrophotometer or titration method?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is-there-any-method-to-determine-urea-in-water-and-phosphate-KH2PO4-in-water-fertilizers-by-UV-VIS-spectrophotometer-or-titration-method) mentioning enzyme biosensor method and spectrophotometic method.

Comment: The presence of salt would interfere with conductivity measurements. A spectroscopic or colorimetric measurement as in the link provided by Poutnik is your best bet.

Comment: Please provide more details. What do you mean by continuous?